# How to revert the sequence back into the initial while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am struggling with this problem where I'm required to write the code for a '2 step' text game. Basically, the game involves a player who is lost in a forest and he is offered a choice to either move left or right. If he moves right, he is prompted to choose again but if he moves left, he gets out and the game ends i.e the code terminates.

If he doesn't choose either of the two, the machine should print 'Answer invalid' and the player should be prompted to choose again .

I am restricted to using the following operators only:
while, if, string, break, continue , else and elif .

I can use string slicing commands as well.

I've managed to write the code for everything apart for the bit that invalidates the player's answer and forces him to choose again.

```
n=input("You are in the Lost Forest. Go Left or Right? ")

        while n!='right' :
          n=input("Invalid answer. Go Left or Right? ")
        else:
          while n =='right':
          n=input("Still Stuck")
        continue

#Here I second while loop keeps repeating but I want the initial while loop to get prompted. I can't move onto the last step for the choice of "going left."
```

Comment: Be sure to mark question as solved if it has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're getting stuck in your way of thinking. What you want to do can be done but it's not the best solution (it'll be improved if you use functions, that'll allow you to return to same loop). Try this though:

```
def my_game():
    print("You're lost.")
    finish = False
    while finish == False:
        ans = input("Go L or R?")
        if ans == "R":
            print("Try again.")
        elif ans == "L": 
            print("You made it.")
            finish = True
        else: 
            print("Invalid answer.")
    if finish: 
        print("Game finished.")
```

Though you should be doing your homework yourself. You should now to try to make it more fun/interactive. Try to return varying answers when you're stuck, allow both small and capital case as valid inputs, add some randomness. Have fun :)